# How to add feature to the training data in Stanford NER CRF

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

How do I make a 3 column training data file using stanford ner crf? Their default training data is just 2 column, which is the tab separated (I've already trained and created a model with that).

What I want to is to make an experiment, what will be the result if I add one feature in the annotation?

For example like this:

`John Capital NAME`

John = Word, Capital = additionalFeature, NAME = Tag/Answer

Comment: There is coverage on this page about adding new features, and how to find and use all possible existing features: https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.html

Comment: If you want to make a new feature, you will have to alter the source code to extract the feature...it's not set up to easily look at a second column.